# Generic Parameter 'self' could not be infered

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

I'm trying to convert bytes in values from a bluetooth device i'm using, but I'm getting `Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred` on this and I don't know what it means

```
var speed: UInt16 = 0
_ = withUnsafeBytes(of: &speed, {characteristic.value!.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 0...1)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The actual problem is that `withUnsafeBytes` invokes the closure with a *read-only* buffer pointer to the raw bytes of the given argument. What you need is `withUnsafeMutableBytes`:

```
var speed: UInt16 = 0
_ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &speed, {
    characteristic.value!.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 0...1)
})
```

Comment: that gives me```Cannot invoke 'copyBytes' with an argument list of type '(to: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer), from: ClosedRange<Int>)'```

Comment: It compiles for me ... apparently we are back to https://stackoverflow.com/q/57061135/1187415. Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.2

Comment: @DisplayName: It compiles without problems in my Xcode 10.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

needed to change to

```
_ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &speed, {
    characteristic.value!.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutuableBufferPointer(to: $0. count: 1), from: 0..<1)
})
```